# How do I correct a token and then recover from a failed predicate in ANTLR?

Tags: parsing, error-handling, antlr, antlr3

I have an ANTLR rule for creating an AST with a predicate test.  It looks like this:

```
checked_rule
  : kwd=keyword name=name nl { noBadChars($name.start.getText()) }?
    -> ^(...)
  ;
```

If `$name` has some bad characters, then I want to have an error.  I'm doing it so far like this:

```
catch [FailedPredicateException fpe] {
  BadNameException error = new BadNameException(input, $kwd.text, $name.start.getText());
  reportError(error);
  recover(input, error);
  retval.tree = (Object)adaptor.errorNode(input, retval.start, input.LT(-1), error);
}
```

That last bit's copied out of ANTLR-generated code, so maybe it's not the right way to do it.

Anyway, what I'd like to do is recover from the error by correcting the name and trying the rule again.  In pseudo-code, I'd like to say:

```
catch [FailedPredicateException fpe] {
  ...
  reportError(...)
  input.LT(-2) = removedBadChars($name.start.getText());
  return checked_rule();
}
```

So the error would still get to the user, but we'd continue the parse with as little disruption as possible.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply do:

```
checked_rule
  : kwd=keyword name=name nl 
    {
      if(!noBadChars($name.start.getText())) {
        // print/report error
        String withoutBadChars = removedBadChars($name.start.getText());
        $name.start.setText(withoutBadChars);
        // and continue happily ever after...
      }
    }
    -> ^(...)
  ;
```

?

Comment: I felt like it would be good to work within the provided Predicate framework rather than rolling my own.  But I tested your suggestion and it does exactly what I wanted and is (IMO) clearer-looking, too.  Thanks!

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot, you *could* use a predicate, but if you're immediately acting upon the exception this predicate throws in the same rule, it's less hassle to use a bit of custom code. And you're welcome.